# Memory leak at a function over an array

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

Hello I would need some help with the following code and memory leak.

Error log from this program shows I`m encountring the following leak in my program:

```
Dr. Memory version 1.4.6 build 2 built on Mar  7 2012 10:14:04
Application cmdline: ""D:\c++\Begin\L_6-8\Debug\L_6-8.exe""
Recorded 62 suppression(s) from default C:\Program Files (x86)\Dr. Memory/bin/suppress-default.txt

Error #1: UNADDRESSABLE ACCESS: reading 0x0077f5a0-0x0077f5a4 4 byte(s)
# 0 Assignment::getID()                              [..//Assignment.h:26]
# 1 AssignmentRepository::searchById()               [D:\c++\Begin\L_6-8\Debug/../AssignmentRepository.cpp:10]
# 2 AssignmentRepository::delByID()                  [D:\c++\Begin\L_6-8\Debug/../AssignmentRepository.cpp:30]
# 3 Catalog::removeAssignment()                      [D:\c++\Begin\L_6-8\Debug/../Catalog.cpp:38]
# 4 _fu63___ZSt4cout                                 [D:\c++\Begin\L_6-8\Debug/../UIconsole.cpp:148]
# 5 UIconsole::runUI()                               [D:\c++\Begin\L_6-8\Debug/../UIconsole.cpp:24]
# 6 Application::run()                               [D:\c++\Begin\L_6-8\Debug/../App.cpp:48]
# 7 main                                             [D:\c++\Begin\L_6-8\Debug/../App.cpp:25]
Note: @0:00:21.491 in thread 6388
Note: refers to 1 byte(s) beyond last valid byte in prior malloc
Note: prev lower malloc:  0x0077f590-0x0077f5a0
Note: instruction: mov    (%eax) -> %eax

Error #2: POSSIBLE LEAK 100 direct bytes 0x0077f5c8-0x0077f62c + 0 indirect bytes
# 0 libstdc++-6.dll!_cxa_allocate_exception
# 1 AssignmentRepository::delByID()               [D:\c++\Begin\L_6-8\Debug/../AssignmentRepository.cpp:36]
# 2 Catalog::removeAssignment()                   [D:\c++\Begin\L_6-8\Debug/../Catalog.cpp:38]
# 3 _fu63___ZSt4cout                              [D:\c++\Begin\L_6-8\Debug/../UIconsole.cpp:148]
# 4 UIconsole::runUI()                            [D:\c++\Begin\L_6-8\Debug/../UIconsole.cpp:24]
# 5 Application::run()                            [D:\c++\Begin\L_6-8\Debug/../App.cpp:48]
# 6 main                                          [D:\c++\Begin\L_6-8\Debug/../App.cpp:25]

DUPLICATE ERROR COUNTS:

SUPPRESSIONS USED:

ERRORS FOUND:
      1 unique,     1 total unaddressable access(es)
      0 unique,     0 total uninitialized access(es)
      0 unique,     0 total invalid heap argument(s)
      0 unique,     0 total warning(s)
      0 unique,     0 total,      0 byte(s) of leak(s)
      1 unique,     1 total,    100 byte(s) of possible leak(s)
ERRORS IGNORED:
     89 still-reachable allocation(s)
         (re-run with "-show_reachable" for details)
Details: C:\Users\Warzaru\AppData\Roaming/Dr. Memory/DrMemory-L_6-8.exe.9752.000/results.txt
```

Considering my function and Repository class were did i do something wrong...

Class Header(full):

```
#ifndef ASSIGNMENTREPOSITORY_H_
#define ASSIGNMENTREPOSITORY_H_

#include "Assignment.h"
#include <vector>

class AssignmentRepository{
private:
    vector <Assignment> assignments;
public:
    vector <Assignment> getAll();
    void save(Assignment);
    void delByID(int);
    void editAssignment(Assignment);
    int searchById(int);
    void printAllAssignments();
    Assignment *getAssignment(int i);

    ~AssignmentRepository();
};

#endif /* ASSIGNMENTREPOSITORY_H_
```

Class cpp(part):

```
int AssignmentRepository::searchById(int a){
for(unsigned i=0; i<assignments.size(); i++){
    if(a == assignments[i].getID()){
        return i;
    }
}
return 0;
}

void AssignmentRepository::delByID(int i){
int check;
check = searchById(i);

if(check != 0){
    assignments.erase(assignments.begin()+check);
}
else{
    throw RepoException("ID does not exist in the database!");
}
}
```

Comment: You haven't shown the relevant code, so it's impossible to say...

Comment: What else should show you ?:|

Comment: Take a look at the top of each stack trace...

Comment: added delByID() ... is it that?

Comment: You do realize that `0` is a valid return value (first element in the vector), and thus a terrible sentinel error value, right?

Comment: I didn't know. I'll keep that in mind. I'll cahnge to -1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theres some exception in this function delByID() or this removeAssignment()

Comment: but why, aren't my functions correct, shouldn't they be working?

Comment: the exception states that something went wrong when you tried to allocate something, although you have an exception the program can run as expected. Be sure to delete() your assignments somewhere as your log says: 89 still-reachable allocation(s)

Comment: thank you.... found the problem I didn't deconstruct one pointer in UIconsole.